# Disqus + ajax + died ...

Tags: ajax, disqus

I've tried to load Disqus with ajax in my page, i'll explain. I have one page inside it i have jqrusel, with differents images and each one have its comments.

So , when i clicked on one of this images, i have done this code:

```
 $.get("/sets/comentarios",{set_id:set_id},function(data){
                $("#componet_comentarios").html(data);
```

and this url load :

```
 var disqus_identifier = 'votar-<?= $id; ?>';
    var disqus_url = 'www.mitrendy.com/votar/<?= $id; ?>';

    // Remove the old script if it's found 
    oldDsq = document.getElementById('MitrendyComentDisqus');
    if(oldDsq) {
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).removeChild(oldDsq);
    }


    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script');
        dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
        dsq.async = true;
        dsq.id = "MitrendyComentDisqus-<?= $id; ?>";
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
```

but never refresh the comments. Later i saw in official page of disqus :

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
});
```

but it's the same, when i tried to load the comments with ajax, never refresh it.

Any idea ? i crazy with it.

Thanks to anybody!!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? We're having trouble with this one. In fact, whenever I give an hashbang URL to disqus, I'm getting 400 bad request error. Any idea?

Comment: No for the moment. I've tried everything but without lucky

Comment: I'm in touch with Disqus' support right now via email. I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: In theory according with the documentation should work with this : DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
}); but doesn't work :(

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I've test this a bit further and discovered that, in my case, the callback function (config) is never called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar problem, I moved my site to ajax and the subpage previously included in php, which contains disqus js, now is loaded using ajax (container for disqus and its scripts) but when this is not loaded with whole page, the scripts are not evaluated. So I moved them to global .js file and wrap in function, like this:

```
var disqus_shortname = 'myname';
var disqus_identifier = 'myident';

function loadDisqus()   {
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
}
```

and after ajax loads content, I call `loadDisqus();` and the board loads.
In your example, you should also pass identifier as parameter and define it when calling,  everything should work properly.

Comment: What is the url you are using for disqus_url. Is it a hashbang (#!), or it's a normal url?

Comment: How do you pass disqus_identifier?